# !Misplaced \omit.\multispan ->\omit@\multispan

Tags: graphics, multicol

I am trying to show 4 .jpg files in 2x2 format using the following:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cccc@{}}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.26]{error1.jpg} 
    \includegraphics[scale=0.26]{afperror1.jpg} \\
    \includegraphics[scale=0.26]{error2.jpg} 
    \includegraphics[scale=0.26]{afperror2.jpg} 
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{\includegraphics[width=.23\textwidth]}
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure}
```

But I get the following error:

```
!Misplaced \omit.\multispan ->\omit@\multispan ...c}
```

which is strange as the image renders fine when viewing the resulting pdf. What is causing this issue?

Comment: you forgot the `\\ ` before the `\multicolumn` and the `&` between your images. (you have a 4 column table but all your entries are in the first column only)

Comment: so you only want 2 columns  `{@{}cc@{}}` not 4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.26]{error1.jpg}            & 
    \includegraphics[scale=0.26]{afperror1.jpg} \\
    \includegraphics[scale=0.26]{error2.jpg}             &
    \includegraphics[scale=0.26]{afperror2.jpg}           \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[width=.23\textwidth]{something}}
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure}
```