# issue using \visible within tabular environment with \multicolumn and booktabs package

Tags: tables, beamer, overlays, multicolumn, booktabs

The following mwe compiles, however, if one exposes the commented text, I receive the error:

```
! Misplaced \noalign
```

In the non-mwe version of the table, I have also received error messages akin to:

```
! Misplaced \omit. \onslide \multicolumn
```

A quick search gives a few examples ([75639](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75639/misplaced-omit-error), [149819](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149819/misplaced-omit-multispan-omit-multispan)) which may be relevant.  Most of these questions/issues were solved by relatively simple fixes.  I very well could be missing somethings basic.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}[h]{lccc}
\toprule
\visible<1->{%
1 & \multicolumn{3}{l}{text$^{a}$} \\[1mm]%
}%
\visible<2->{%
1 & \multicolumn{3}{l}{text} \\[1mm]%
}%
\visible<3->{%
1 & \multicolumn{3}{l}{text} \\[1mm]%
}%
\visible<4->{%
 & $\ell_{x, y}$ & $\ell_{z}$ & $\tau$ \\
\cmidrule{2-4}
A & B & C & D \\[1mm]%
}%
\visible<5->{%
A & B & C & D \\[1mm]
}%
\visible<6->{%
A & B & C & D \\[1mm]
}%
%\midrule
%\visible<1->{%
%\multicolumn{4}{l}{\tiny\textcolor{gray}{$^{a}$a detailed note which spans columns.}} \\%
%}%
%\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** As suggested by one answer, I have replaced the `\visible`s by `\pause`s, which worked. However, after adding further `\multicolumn`s (footnotes essentially which are intended to be exposed at different times) I still receive the `! Misplaced \omit` error.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}[h]{lccc}
    \toprule
    1 & \multicolumn{3}{l}{text$^{a}$} \\[1mm]%
\pause
    1 & \multicolumn{3}{l}{text} \\[1mm]%
\pause
    1 & \multicolumn{3}{l}{text$^{b}$} \\[1mm]%
\pause
      & $\ell_{x, y}$ & $\ell_{z}$ & $\tau$ \\
    \cmidrule{2-4}
    A & B & C & D \\[1mm]%
\pause
    A & B & C & D \\[1mm]
\pause
    A & B & C & D 
\pause[1]
                  \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{4}{l}{\tiny\textcolor{gray}{$^{a}$a detailed note which spans columns.}}
\pause[3]    
                  \\%
    \multicolumn{4}{l}{\tiny\textcolor{gray}{$^{b}$another note which spans columns.}}
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no direct fix, but get it to work by using `\pause` (once with optional argument) instead of `\visible`. Note that for some reason `\midrule` prefers to follow directly after `\\[1mm]` and gives an error when putting `\pause` inbetween.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}[h]{lccc}
    \toprule
    1 & \multicolumn{3}{l}{text$^{a}$} \\[1mm]%
\pause
    1 & \multicolumn{3}{l}{text} \\[1mm]%
\pause
    1 & \multicolumn{3}{l}{text} \\[1mm]%
\pause
      & $\ell_{x, y}$ & $\ell_{z}$ & $\tau$ \\
    \cmidrule{2-4}
    A & B & C & D \\[1mm]%
\pause
    A & B & C & D \\[1mm]
\pause
    A & B & C & D 
\pause[1]
                  \\[1mm]
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{4}{l}{\tiny\textcolor{gray}{$^{a}$a detailed note which spans columns.}} \\%
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The fix suggested by @gernot worked.  I have updated the code to include multiple instances of `\multicolumn`; footnotes essentially which are intended to be exposed at different times.  I tried to employ the approach of having the `\pause` command precede the `\\\` without luck.  I receive the `! Misplaced \omit` error.

Comment: There are two problems: You forgot `\\ ` before the `\bottomrule`; without it, your code doesn't compile even without `\pause`s. The second is, that `\multicolumn` wants to sit alone in its tabular cell and accepts `\pause` (and other stuff) neither before nor after it. However, you can put the `\pause` commands into the multicolumn text, like that:  `\multicolumn{4}{l}{\pause[3]\tiny\textcolor{gray}{$^{b}$ ....}\pause[1]}\\ `

Comment: Putting the `\pause` command within the `\multicolumn` works well.  I should point out that I had originally wanted to implement a `\newcommand` in order to abstract away some of the code associated with the `\multicolumn`.  This fix makes a little more work, less elegant in that the overlay commands are mixed in with the content.  I'm likely ignoring some of the difficulty in achieving complete separation (of content and overlay directives), though.